# How can I get host in a Controller using MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

I would like to get a HOST name to apply an specific role for on host, because I have 2 websites hosted for the same application folder.

I need get a HOST in my Controller to define this role.

Some like this:

```
public override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);

    if (host == "mycustomhost.com")
    {
        ViewBag.Theme = "CustomTheme";
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Theme = "DefaultTheme";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
public override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);

    var customHost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CustomHost"];
    string theme = String.Empty;

    if (customHost.ToLower().Contains(requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host.ToLower()))
    {
        ViewBag.Theme = "CustomTheme";
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Theme = "DefaultTheme";
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 although I prefer `customHost.Equals(requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` for comparing strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    var hostname = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host;

    // do something based on 'hostname' value
    // ....

    base.Initialize(requestContext);
}
```